# Weird float behavior for li w/images

Tags: css, css-float

Not sure how to describe it. Why aren't the last two `li` floating correctly?

Site: http://symphonyninjas.com/interviews/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LIs are all floating, but the images are different heights. The fifth image is hitting the third image and sitting next to it instead of underneath it.

Clear the float when you want to start a new row. You already have a class on that LI to remove the margin, simply add clear:left;

```
.photo-id.first, .first.interviewee {
    [...]
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think the different sizes in images were a problem as long as the aspect ratio was the same; it turns out that the third image aspect ratio is off by 1 pixel causing the problem. Thank you for finding the needle as to why! Had me stumped and was focusing on the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Add `clear:left`:

```
.photo-id.first, .first.interviewee {
   margin-left: 0;
   clear: left;
}
```